# Partial derivative of function that relies on given gradient of another function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable such that $\nabla f(2,3)=(3,4)$

We'll define $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x,y)=f(x^2-y+2 , y^3-x+3)$

And I'm asked to find $g_x(1,1)$

I'm trying to solve this by definition, like so: $g_x(1,1)=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{g(1+\Delta x,1)-g(1,1)}{\Delta x}$ and finding the limit.

What bugs me is so:

Can I claim that due to how $g$ is defined (using $f$),

I can exchange $g_x(x,y)$ for $f_x(x^2-y+2,y^3-x+3)$ and find $g_x(1,1)$ in that manner?

If not, what would be the right path of though in approaching this exercise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can exchange.

Comment: @Ramanujan I'm a bit confused on how does this work, can you share a small explanation on why this is a legitimate exchange?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if two things are equal, you can exchange them for each other.

Comment: @Aishgadol  No. Do not try from first principles.  Just use the Chain Rule.

Comment: @Aishgadol  How did you go?

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x^2-y+2$ and $v=y^3-x+3$, you see that
$u=2,v=3$ when $x=1,y=1$

Taking differentials, it holds
$du=2xdx,dv=-dx$
From here
$$
dg 
= f_u du + f_v dv
= (2x f_u-f_v) dx
$$
The bracket term is the derivative you need i.e. $g_x$

All it remains is to perform the numerical evaluation
$g_x(1,1) = 2\cdot 1\cdot 3 - 4 = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

No.  That is the wrong approach since it does not allow you to use the information provided.

You have that $\nabla f~(2,3)=\langle 3,4\rangle$, which is helpful since if $u(x,y)=x^2-y+2,$ and $v(x,y)=y^3-x+3$, then $\nabla f~(u(1,1),v(1,1))=\nabla f~(2,3)$ .

Remember that $\nabla f(u,v)= \langle f_u(u,v), f_v(u,v)\rangle$ and by the Chain Rule: $$g_x(x,y)=f_u(u(x,y),v(x,y))\, u_x(x,y)+f_v(u(x,y),v(x,y))\, v_x(x,y)$$